# Find Time difference between 2 datetimes ignoring date portion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I simply need to take two datetime objects, subtract them to get the time difference in hours. I do not care about the date portion in the calculation. If you have 1/1/02 11:00:00 - 1/1/02 9:00:00 then i would get 2 as the result. If the difference is 30 or greater, round to 1. The time objects im using are the currenttime and a column containing the other datetime object.

Comment: In sql server 2012 you can cast a datetime as a time.  select CAST(getdate() as time).  If I were on 2008, I'd at least try it.  Then you can use datediff as per the two answers.

Comment: @DanBracuk SQL Server 2008 has the `TIME` datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use the `TIME` datatype:

```
SELECT ABS(ROUND(DATEDIFF(MI,CONVERT(TIME,date1), CONVERT(TIME,date2))/60.0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If time direction matters use this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, <date1>, <date2>) % 24...
```

Or if you just want the absolute time difference:

```
SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, <date1>, <date2>) % 24)...
```

Comment: Missed the rounding.  @Lamak has the better answer.